# Is it possible to import multiple Vue plugins using a loop? To avoid typing all files manually

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I would like to replace this part of code with some loop that will import all `.js` files from a specified directory (plugins in this example).

```
import AlertPlugin from '@/plugins/AlertPlugin';
Vue.use(AlertPlugin);

import AxiosPlugin from '@/plugins/AxiosPlugin';
Vue.use(AxiosPlugin);

import ConfigPlugin from '@/plugins/ConfigPlugin';
Vue.use(ConfigPlugin);

import TranslationPlugin from '@/plugins/TranslationPlugin';
Vue.use(TranslationPlugin);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with [babel-plugin-wildcard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-wildcard)

```
import * as plugins from './plugins/';
Object.keys(plugins).forEach(key => {
   Vue.use(plugins[key]);
});
```